# how to remove just one character in a string of javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
#a:{width:100px;height:100px;background-color:black;}#b:{width:100px;}
```

i have the above string

i want that the character`:` only after css selector like `#a` and `#b` get removed from this string

i thought that i must use regular expressions so i wrote one:

```
/[#\.A-Za-z0-9]+([:])[{]/g
```

see this regular expression working on **[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eW8pS6/3)**

but you know it matches `:` but when i try to remove this using `replace` method then whole `#a:{` and `#b:{` get removed

any help would be great!

Comment: Why don't you remove the `:` before the `{`? (replace `/:\{/g` with `"{"`) Should be a lot easier and safer than defining what a CSS selector looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is almost correct. What you need to do is to repalce the with `$1$2` instead of null string

Also make a small change to the regex as

```
/([#.A-Za-z0-9]+):({)/g
```

[**Regex Example**](https://regex101.com/r/eW8pS6/6)

**Changes made**

- `([#.A-Za-z0-9]+)` enclosed in brackets. The matched string is captured in `$1` hence for the frist match `$1` will contain `#a`

  - Within a character class its not required to escape the `.` as it looses it meaning in the class.
- `[{]` to `({)` The `[]` surrounding does not make any difference, hence drop it. Enclosed in `()`, hence captured in `$2`, for example in first match the `$2` will contian `{`
- Replace string `$1$2`

  will give output as

  ```
  #a{width:100px;height:100px;background-color:black;} #b{width:100px;}
  ```

Comment: but what if i dont know that number of matched items. i mean if the pattern is x times matched then how i will actually replace all the matched items

Comment: @Annisaini since you are using the `g` flag, for each matching of the regex, the match is caputred and relpaced with the corresponding value in `$1` and `$2` . See the example https://regex101.com/r/eW8pS6/7

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript**

```
var value = "#a:{width:100px;height:100px;background-color:black;}#b:{width:100px;}";
alert(value.replace(/(#.):/g, "$1"));
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7hs0jgd2/

[image]